# User input regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I want to write a regular expression in C# so that the user can input a word he is looking for. For example:
User writes in to a textBox in WPF the name of a movie.
In C# I store that text input into a string variable.

How can I add that variable to a regular expression?

```
        string nameOfMovie = textBox.Text;
        string reg = @".*(nameOfMovie).*";
```

In the end I want to see all the movies in a List for example that contain the entered word.

P.s. I know it can be done a lot quicker with c# built in string functions but I want to use regular expressions.

Comment: What's wrong with `string reg = ".*(" + nameOfMovie + ").*";`? (Or alternatively in C#6+, `string reg = $".*({nameOfMovie}).*";`)

Comment: what would be the input?

Comment: @Abion47 thank you soooo much :D

Comment: putting the user input directly into a regular expression introduces a regular expression vulnerability-- a malicious user can denial-of-service attack you by putting in a computationally difficult pattern.  You should sanitize the input and build the regular expression with care to avoid this.

Comment: If you must use regular expressions you should also escape the name like this `string reg = ".*(" + Regex.Escape(nameOfMovie) + ").*";` in case the name contains any characters that have a special meaning for regular expressions (unless you want the user to be able to include regular expression syntax).